# One custom trigger with multiple events EXTJS

Tags: extjs, triggers

I am working on a UI and I am looking to have two search boxes that will call different events. I was wondering if I can implement one trigger with multiple events.

Below is the code of the trigger with its onTriggerClick:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomTrigger', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
    alias: 'widget.customTrigger',
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.triggerCls = 'x-form-search-trigger'; // native ExtJS class & icon
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    onTriggerClick: function(){
        alert('Hello');
    }
});

Ext.define('DIN.view.DINView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ],
    xtype: 'app-main',

    items: [
        {   
            xtype: 'customTrigger',
            fieldLabel: 'trigger1',
            emptyText: 'trigger1',
            margin: '5 5 5 5',
            border: 'true',
            textAlign: 'left',
        },
        {

            xtype: 'customTrigger',
            fieldLabel: 'trigger2',
            emptyText: 'trigger2',
            margin: '5 5 5 5',
            border: 'true',
            textAlign: 'left',
        }]
});
```

How can I have trigger1 fire a different event from trigger2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have trigger2 use a different handler than trigger1, just override it like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',


    launch: function() {
        var app = this;
        Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomTrigger', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
            alias: 'widget.customTrigger',
            initComponent: function() {
                var me = this;
                me.triggerCls = 'x-form-search-trigger'; // native ExtJS class & icon
                me.callParent(arguments);
            },
            onTriggerClick: function() {
                alert("Default Action");
            }
        });

        Ext.define('DINView', {
            extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
            requires: ['Ext.grid.Panel'],
            xtype: 'app-main',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'customTrigger',
                fieldLabel: 'trigger1',
                emptyText: 'trigger1',
                margin: '5 5 5 5',
                border: 'true',
                textAlign: 'left',
            }, {

                xtype: 'customTrigger',
                fieldLabel: 'trigger2',
                emptyText: 'trigger2',
                margin: '5 5 5 5',
                border: 'true',
                textAlign: 'left',
                onTriggerClick: function() {
                    alert("We'll override this one");
                }
            }]
        });

        Ext.create("DINView", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

When you define `Ext.ux.CustomTrigger` you can set default settings and handlers etc but you always have the choice of overriding the config on a per element basis. In my [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gan) and the code above you can see that the default action is to display an alert saying 'Default Action' but on trigger2 I re-define the event handler to call alert with "We'll override this one".

Comment: Thank you! that makes perfect sense; I was trying to add an onTriggerClick listener to each trigger and was having no luck. I appreciate it